# JSON: Drill down & manipulate nested objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have this `foo` `object`, it is dynamic object - `foo` object can have a nested `parent` `object` which also can have a nested `parent` `object` and so on.. In this scenario, what is the best way to:

1) Get the last object that has a parent?

2) Populate an array with all nested parent objects + the first obj (foo.obj)?

```
 foo: {
    caption: "Italian",
    code: "",
    id: 17,
    parent: {
       caption: "Restaurants",
       code: "",
       id: 9,
       parent: {
          caption: "Food and Drink",
          code: "food_and_drink",
          id: 1,
          parent: ""
      }
   }
};
```

is it a work for a `while`?

Comment: Is it a homework, isn't it?

Comment: This is work for a recursive function.

Comment: You could use a while loop, have a variable which holds the last parent as you encounter it and push onto an array each time you encounter a parent. Or, as mentioned above you could use a recursive function that takes an object and an array and does the same as above, except passes the modified array and the first parent found as a new object to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only vanilla JS.

1a. Approach with loop:

```
function findLastParent(el) {
    var parent = el,
        notFound = true;
    while (notFound) {
        if (parent.parent) {
            parent = parent.parent
        } else {
            notFound = false;
        }
    }
    return parent;
}
```

1b. Approach with recursion (be careful with call stack size, cuz every time new function pointer is created):

```
function findLastParent(el) {
    if (el.parent) {
        return findLastParent(el.parent)
    } else {
        return el
    }
}
```

2a. Approach with recursion (with loop will be similar to the code from the 1 point):

```
function getAsArray(el, acc) {
    acc.push(el);
    if (el.parent) {
        return getAsArray(el.parent, acc);
    } else {
        return acc;
    }
}
var result = getAsArray(root,[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursivity is what you are looking for.
You need to:

#### #1 Create a function to receive an object and test if it has anything inside its parent property.

#### #2 If your object.parent has data, you have to Iterate inside that object.  Iterate(OBJ.parent)

#### #3 If your object has no data, this must be the last element, (return OBJ).

When you solve this problem, you might give a try to solve it again with multiple parents / nodes, and try to print all the elements in the latest nodes

```js
foo: {
        caption: "Italian",
        code: "",
        id: 17,
        parent: {
           caption: "Restaurants",
           code: "",
           id: 9,
           parent:[ {
              caption: "Chairs and Tables",
              code: "chairs_and_tables",
              id: 2,
              parent: ""
           },
           {
              caption: "Food and Drink",
              code: "food_and_drink",
              id: 1,
              parent: ""
          }]
       }
}
```